# Question about the application of the WLLN

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, statistical-inference

Let $g(x,t)$ be a continous at $t_0$ uniformaly in x. Let $F$ be a distribution function for which $E_F|g(X,t_0)|<\infty$. Let $\{X_i\}$ be i.i.d with d.f F and suppose that $T_n\rightarrow_p t_0$. Then,

$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n g(X_i, T_n)\rightarrow_pE_Fg(X,t_0)$

Futher, the convergence in probability can be replaced by a.s convergence throughout.

My question:
It seems that

According to WLLn, we have $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n g(X_i, t_0)\rightarrow_pE_Fg(X,t_0)$.   Since $T_i \rightarrow t_0$, and $g(x,t)$ be continous at $t_0$ uniformaly in x, we have $ g(X_i, T_n)\rightarrow_p g(X,t_0)$ according to continous mapping, thus $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n g(X_i, T_n)\rightarrow_pE_Fg(X,t_0)$

In the statement about , we can replace convergence in probability with almost sure convergence.

That is $T_n\rightarrow_{a.s}   t_0$, then $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n g(X_i, T_n)\rightarrow_{a.s} E_Fg(X,t_0)$ (continous mapping and SLLN)

Comment: You don't seem to have used the continuity properties of $g$ at all, and that's not a proper application of LLN, at least not the vanilla version... the terms aren't iid.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I use Borel-Cantelli lemma to show?  Not good at analysis. I will make some change.

Comment: This strikes me as a "grind it out" kind of problem. For instance, if you just had $g(X_i,t_0)$ then this iid issue I brought up (which on closer reading, wasn't the most exact way to describe it) wouldn't be a problem and you could just use LLN. But what can we say (precisely) about $|g(X_i,t_0)-g(X_i, T_n)|$ as $n$ gets large? Unfortunately my time is too short (and my analysis too rusty) to write a solution, but hopefully that hint is at least helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I will make some change.  Just think B-C is an efficient way to a.s convergence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases the result follows from the (weak or strong) [uniform law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Uniform_law_of_large_numbers) (*continuous mapping theorem doesn't apply to this situation*). Specifically, let $Q_n(t):=n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n g(X_i,t)$ and $Q(t):=\mathsf{E}g(X,t)$. Then
\begin{align}
|Q_n(T_n)-Q(t_0)|&\le |Q_n(T_n)-Q(T_n)|+|Q(T_n)-Q(t_0)| \\
&\le \sup_{t\in \mathcal{T}}|Q_n(t)-Q(t)|+|Q(T_n)-Q(t_0)|,
\end{align}
where $\mathcal{T}$ is the parameter space. When $t\mapsto Q(t)$ is continuous the second term converges to $0$ (a.s. or in probability). The first term converges to $0$ by the referenced uniform LLN (assuming that $\mathcal{T}$ is compact and $\mathsf{E}\sup_{t\in\mathcal{T}}|g(X,t)|<\infty$).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your nice explanation.! Why continuous mapping theorem can not apply to this situation.  It seems that  $f$ is continuous and $T_n \rightarrow t_0$.

Comment: Let's try to use your argument. First,
\begin{align}
Q_n(T_n)(\omega)-Q(t_0)&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (g(X_i(\omega),T_n(\omega))-g(X_i(\omega),t_0)) \\
&\quad+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (g(X_i(\omega),t_0)-\mathsf{E}g(X,t_0)).
\end{align}
By the SLLN (for almost all $\omega$) the second term converges to $0$. Also for almost all $\omega$, $g(X_i(\omega),T_n(\omega))-g(X_i(\omega),t_0)\to 0$. However, you're missing an argument showing that their average converges to $0$ a.s. as well.